# ESO basic game: what are the regions I can't access?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Got a bunch of treasure maps and it's annoying how it's not immediately clear which I have access to from the base game. I don't buy any additional dlc as a rule of thumb.

I think Murkmire, Vvardenfell and Hew's Bane are off limits and I can ditch those treasure maps. Any others? Pet hate games that try to lead you into blocked content like that, same with jewelry crafting.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily get rid of the maps since ESO has had a "free ESO plus" event before and may again in the future.

Comment: Vvardenfell you have already access to, they have added morrowind to the basic game. Infact if you start a new character it should put you in Vvardenfell.

Comment: Possible answer [here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/225207/108888) I haven't played in a long time, so I'm not sure how applicable it still is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully correct answer depends on when you bought the game.

For example, if you bought the base game after the Summerset release in May 2018, then these are the zones you would have to purchase as Crown Store DLC:

- Gold Coast
- Imperial City
- Morrowind/Vvardenfell
- Murkmire
- Orsinium/Wrothgar
- Clockwork City
- Hew’s Bane

You can find out which zones are separate purchases by going to the Crown Store and looking at the DLC.